# Bootstrap4 table in django

Tags: django, bootstrap-4, html-table

I am a beginner to both Django and Python and have been working through a simplified example table for a future project idea, using a bootstrapped ver. 4 (sb-admin template style) connected to my model, which, for the most part shows correctly except for one aspect.

I have set my table class to: table table-bordered table-hover table-striped

I have also added coloured emphasis arguments for one column of data and emphasis colour to another to show that it is calculated and that is working as expected.

However, when I attempt to change the table head row class to dark (which I think looks nicer), I lose the striped and hover formatting table elements I mentioned above.

In addition, I lose my emphasis colour functionality (except on hover), if I attempt to change the table class to table-sm in order to make things smaller and more compact.

Any ideas for someone that wants it all? Is this just a limitation to the free bootstrap style?